# rosout and stderr not appearing in ROS_LOG_DIR

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, environment-variables, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed the ROS_LOG_DIR from the default and now I am only seeing node specific stdout.log files in the generated folders. I know my nodes are generating stderr messages with ROS_ERROR_STREAM but I don't see any ERROR messages in the log or a rosout.log file.

Is there an additional setting I need to set for the rosout.log file and error logs to go to the ROS_LOG_DIR ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363926/rosout-and-stderr-not-appearing-in-ros_log_dir/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2020-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that rosout.log is written by roscore and not each node as I had originally believed. I had roscore running in a separate location that did not have write permissions to that folder which is why rosout.log was not being generated. After resolving this, the log appears as normal.

---

Originally posted by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) with karma: 268 on 2020-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0